# Equivalent to ZwQueryVirtualMemory that works on system memory?

Tags: windows, kernel

ZwQueryVirtualMemory reports on virtual memory in the address space of a process. I would like to do the same thing, but for paged memory in system space. Is there an equivalent function that deals with system space instead of process space?

Comment: no equivalent. better ask what you really need

Comment: I need to find the total size of a loaded kernel driver in order to dump the whole thing without causing a page fault bugcheck

Comment: walk by section image headers and dump section by section

Comment: tysm I'll do it now

Answer (score 0):

You could use ZwQuerySystemInformation with SystemModuleInformation to get all running drivers. Then you can find the entry you want and get the base and size of the driver. You could if you want to do it properly only get the base of a driver with using the same method of above or using the PsLoadedModuleList to get the base of the targeted driver and then just walk the sections manually with the headers.

Also a tip, if you are going to copy it to dump it, use MmCopyMemory.